Will Branch and Bound always terminate after finite iterations?
I learnt this algorithm by a simple example illustrating the essential ideas of it without analyzing in details. So my questions are

Will BB always end after finite iterations? (Both for binary cases and more general cases, mixed integer programming problem), and Why?
If BB can stop after finite iterations, the return of BB have two cases:

2.1 All of sub-problems listed as leaves are infeasible, then how to gurantee the original IP has no feasible solutions?
2.2 Find a best integral solution of a sub-problem, then how to guarantee it is the optimal solution of my original IP?

Hint: Consider whether all variables are bounded or not.
